# Mount S3 Bucket on AWS ECS

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, mount, amazon-ecs

I am trying to setup Jenkins server on AWS ECS, but I am having to issue mounting S3 to my Docker container.

Can anyone provide me task definition which can mount s3 bucket with Service of ECS? soi can store my Jenkins workspace on s3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install s3fs in your EC2 instances (or may be use a custom AMI for your ECS cluster). Mount the S3 bucket in the EC2 instance and then you can always share the host path.

Answer (score 4):

Consider that S3 is a storage platform with very specific characteristics; it doesn't allow for partial update, it doesn't actually has a folder structure and so on. On the surface it might have a lot of similarities with a filesystem, but it is not build to be one nor should it be used as one.

You can create and attach EBS or EFS volumes to your Docker container. Alternatively, you could use or create a plugin that stores some data on S3 with the specific API's that S3 has.

Comment: Can i mount EFS direct inside ECS service or i need to mount it on EC2 First ??