# S3 bucket persistent storage for docker container

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, containers, amazon-ecs, persistent-volumes

Im trying to mount S3 Bucket as data storage persistent in container ECS but i'm getting an error using EC2 and using ECS EC2
Can you help me please to fix this error ?

[here the config and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFl0t.png)

Comment: Not sure if you have looked at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52041550/mount-s3-bucket-as-filesystem-on-aws-ecs-container

Comment: @tomarv2 yes i have tried it but i had the same error as in the image i've posted with my question "here the config and the error"

Comment: @AnthonyMiller it's just a picture that i have add when i wrote my question and a link is generated to it